# scrollable drop down list

Tags: javascript, menu, drop-down-menu, scrollable

I am trying to figure this out. Here is the sample code

```
<select>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
</select>
```

How do you make this scrollable? Say you want it to only show 3 options, scrollable to the last one and still a drop down menu. Many have suggested using the `attr "size"` that comes with `<select>`. That will give out scrollable effect but not what I have in mind.

So is this even possible? I have been researching the forum, and many suggested to use `<div>` tag with style `overflow auto`. But I am just wondering if it is possible to create scrollable drop down menu.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

it becomes scollable by default if the length exzeeds a limit. i don't know whether this is browser specific but in chromed 11 / ubuntu select dropdowns become scrollable with the 21th entry.

Comment: hmm.. can it be controlled to more specific needs?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one..Here the dropdown becomes listbox when it is selected and returns to it's previous condition when either any option is selected or focus is removed from it.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/StbLB/)

```
    <select name="select1" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8){this.size=10;}" onchange='this.size=0;' onblur="this.size=0;">
...
...
</select>
```